# Check status for current logged user

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I have table with next values..

```
id------username-----password------status
1---------derek--------123---------admin
2----------rob---------321---------worker
```

After login which is working right i need to check on landing page if user has status admin so i could add another html tables and forms for him.

I realize that the query must be something like this.

`SELECT * FROM users where username = '$login_session' and status="status"`

What is the right way for doing this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the statue back to the application, just select it:

```
SELECT status
FROM   users
WHERE  username = '$login_session'
```

Mandatory comment:
Using string evaluation in SQL queries is a bad practice that leaves your application open to SQL-injection attacks. Instead, you should consider using a [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Comment: I understand, this is just learning for now.But how do i generate if statement if admin is true and post some tables for him ?